# how to set sbt proxy in windows

Tags: java, scala, proxy, sbt

my sbtconfig.txt is like this:

```
# Set the java args to high

-Xmx512M

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m



# Set the extra SBT options

-Dsbt.log.format=true



-Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.toshiba.co.jp -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

and it doesn't work. Could someone help me set the proxy in windows? Thanks!

Comment: I never used sbtconfig.txt. But maybe you have to move -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 to the next line?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy and the [SBT setup notes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Setup-Notes.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your sbtconfig.txt, you have given the proxy details as a URL. Remove that and add something like this. It is better to have both the http and https entries in the configuration. Replace the entries given in CAPS with your proper values.

-Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXYHOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=PROXYPORT -Dhttp.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXX

-Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXYHOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=PROXYPORT -Dhttps.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttps.proxyPassword=XXXX