# Is there an online repository with sbt-maven-plugin?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm working on a Play Framework project and I wanted to add Maven compatibility. So I tried to add a plugin which understands `pom.xml`. Unfortunately this does not work.

I'm using [sbt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin) with this line in my `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.shivawu" % "sbt-maven-plugin" % "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT")
```

I also added the repository:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

After `reload` command in Play console it gave this error:

[image]

Anyone an idea how to fix this? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** Make sure you work with `project/plugins.sbt`, use `https` for the repository and that you're not behind a firewall that blocks access to the repo or [configure proxy appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13803459/1305344).

According to the [the official documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin#configuration) you should be using the following instead:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.shivawu" % "sbt-maven-plugin" % "0.1.2")
```

It didn't work for me, either, and I had to add the following repository to `resolvers` in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

The complete `project/plugins.sbt` becomes as follows:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.shivawu" % "sbt-maven-plugin" % "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT")

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

With the setup build worked fine:

```
[info] downloading https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.1.3-SNAPSHOT/sbt-maven-plugin-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.shivawu#sbt-maven-plugin;0.1.3-SNAPSHOT!sbt-maven-plugin.jar (1664ms)
```

What's interesting is that there's [0.2.0-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/) version available, too, yet [build.sbt of the project](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin/blob/master/build.sbt) doesn't seem to show the version could've been possible since `0.1.3-SNAPSHOT` is the next version being worked on.

Comment: I'm using this build.sbt: `name := "testbuildsbt"

version := "0.1"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.3")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.9.0.0"
`

and this `plugins.sbt` `addSbtPlugin("com.github.shivawu" % "sbt-maven-plugin" % "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT")

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"`

and still it cannot find `sbt-maven-plugin` any ideas?