# How to use sbt from behind proxy - in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sbt, http-proxy

I am trying to run `SBT` on *Windows 7*. To do so I followed the steps in the similar thread "[How to use sbt from behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy)".

I have the following relevant "System variables":

Variable name: 
`JAVA_OPTS` 
Variable value: 
`-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`

Variable name: 
`SBT_OPTS` 
Variable value: 
`-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`

and

Variable name: 
`SBT_HOME` 
Variable value: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\`

I also changed the content of `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt`

> ***** sbtconfig.txt BEGINNING *****
>
> *Set the java args to high
>
> -Xmx512M
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>
> -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
>
> *Set the extra SBT options
>
> -Dsbt.log.format=true
>
> *Set proxy
>
> -Dhttp.proxySet=true
>
> -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150
>
> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
>
> ***** sbtconfig.txt END *****

Running `cmd.exe` I enter `sbt`. The cmd echos

> Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ....

After around 1 minute i get a lot of warnings and errors like:

> [...]
>
> :::: ERRORS Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11.ivys/ivy.xml
>
> [...]

which is exactly the same I get without the proxy settings. Also I was surprised when I entered the mentioned address in my browser and all I got was:

> ***** Browser display BEGINNING *****
>
> {
>
> "errors" : [ {
>
> "status" : 404,
>
> "message" : "File not found."
>
> } ]
>
> }
>
> ***** Browser display END *****

How can I find out if SBT is even trying to use the proxy, or there is a different problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you Paweł for your answer.

This is what I found out:

"`-Dhttp.proxySet=true`" doesn't have any effect (for me at least)

The settings are prioritized in the following order:

SBT_OPTS overrides JAVA_OPTS overrides %SBT_HOME%conf\sbtconfig.txt

The Solution is either to set one of the environmental variables

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

OR

```
SBT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

OR to edit the %SBT_HOME%conf\sbtconfig.txt file :

```
***** sbtconfig.txt BEGINNING (hashtags in this file have been replaced by stars) *****

*Set the java args to high

-Xmx512M

*-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m

*Set the extra SBT options

-Dsbt.log.format=true

*Proxy settings

-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 

-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080

-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.150 

-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080

***** sbtconfig.txt END *****
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at your errors:

```
:::: ERRORS Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11.ivys/ivy.xml
```

Sbt is trying to use https, but you don't have proxy configuration for it.
Try setting https proxy variables:

- https.proxyHost
- https.proxyPort

I guess you could try the same values as for http proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your SBT folder and use the below command

```
set SBT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.10.10.154 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.10.10.154 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost <Enter your IP settings >
```

and then

```
sbt.bat
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the proxy settings directly in sbtopt file present in /usr/share/sbt/conf/

Answer (score 0):

sbt uses Gigahorse with OkHttp for parallel downloading. You can try turning it off by passing -Dsbt.gigahorse=false.

Another thing you could try is turning off https, and use http by passing -Dsbt.repository.secure=false

Reference: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4307