# Where can I set proxy for SBT in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, proxy, sbt

I am using `Intellij IDEA 14.1.3` edition and have installed `Scala` plugin. When creating `SBT` project, it reports the following error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\xiaona\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11

See complete log in C:\Users\xiaona\.IdeaIC14\system\log\sbt.last.log
```

After referring this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127687/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy-in-windows-7), I see the root cause should be that I use proxy to connect internet.

But in `SBT` setting screen:
[image]

I can't find a place to set proxy. Where can I set proxy for `SBT` in `Intellij IDEA`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_server> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy_port>` to VM parameters

Read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) for more info

Comment: I actually had to add `https.proxyHost` `https.proxyPort` `https.proxyUser` and `https.proxyPassword` as well

Comment: @Sergey Lagutin: It seems "Global SBT settings" is no use, right?

Comment: Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> SBT -> Global SBT settings -> JVM Options -> VM parameters

Comment: does this mean that user and pwd should be specified and left in clear there?!

Comment: @mdm yes, it's terrible. possible way to solve it is use system variables or another config file

Comment: @SergeyLagutin can you please point to documentation where these parameters are mentioned?

Comment: @Haspemulator check the documentation. The link's added.

Answer (score 15):

Basically there are three ways of setting the proxy. Each of them seems to affect a different part of the IDE.

For all following three methods I recommend setting both, `http` and `https`, since most connections to repos are established using `https` nowadays:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxyAdress 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=yourPort 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=yourUsername 
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourPassword 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=yourProxyAdress
-Dhttps.proxyPort=yourPort 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=yourUsername 
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=yourPassword
```

**1. Build Tools**

Setting the proxy under "Build, Execution, Deployment" > "Build Tools" > "SBT" > "VM parameters" affects the SBT process that is executed after editing the `build.sbt` file and refreshing the latter. Also, this is used for indexing (and therefore auto completion). This setting will also affect the download of SBT itself in the version you selected during project setup.

**2. Other Settings**

Aditionally, I used the setting under "Other Settings" > "SBT" > "VM parameters"

[image: Setting VM parameters]

**3. Setting the proxy globally**

Another way would be to set the proxy settings globally with your `JAVA_OPTS` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy).

Comment: There is no 2) (Other Settings) in 2018 version of InteliJ or am I missing something?

Comment: I have 'Other Settings' but SBT is not listed under it.

Comment: For those who use newer version, just find the sbt settings and change the VM parameters. (E.g. "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "sbt"

Answer (score 10):

Add parameter VM

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=hostName 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=portUse 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=proxyName 
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=proxyPaword
```

It work for me

Comment: I have a proxy but it doesn't need any username/password. Still do we need to set it?

Answer (score 3):

In my situation I have tried all above solutions, but they did not work.

In the end I have configured HTTP proxy for the whole `IntellJ`, and that have resolved my issues.

```
Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Http Proxy
```

[image: settings]

Comment: Setting it here didn't work for me - it still gives me a 'connection timed out' error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a sbt-based scala project you may need to add the proxy in the run configuration of the project:
Run -> Edit configurations...->->VM parameters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same error message and tried all the suggestions mentioned in multiple (related) threads. I was able to finally resolve the problem by setting up the HTTP Proxy directly in IntelliJ. Here's what my settings look like (Note: specify your network username and password in the corresponding boxes):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that in my case, something was picking up the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. Correctly setting (or in my case, unsetting, as I did not wish to use a proxy) these variables solved the proxy errors I was getting.