# Proxy settings for SBT from IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to use Scala/Spark from IntelliJ in Windows 7, but it IntelliJ (and SBT command line) fails to download files. I am behind a proxy server.

```
        [info] Updating {file:/D:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/untitled17/project/}untitled17-build...
        [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy (452ms)
        [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy (157ms)
        [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): public: unable to get resource for org/apache/logging/log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy (115ms)
        [warn]  Detected merged artifact: [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar):  (0ms).
        [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
        [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
        [warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar
        [warn] ==== local: tried
        [warn]   d:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
        [warn] ==== public: tried
        [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
        [warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
        [warn]   d:\Users\user1\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
        [warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
        [warn]   file:/d:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
        [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        [warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
        [warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
        [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        [warn]  :: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
        [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
```

Similar problems were already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127687/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy-in-windows-7).

Already tried:

- SBT versions 0.13.16, 1.0.3 and 1.1.1
- setting proxy properties JAVA_OPTS, SBT_OPTS, sbtconfigtxt

  ```
      -Dhttp.proxyHost=*
      -Dhttp.proxyPort=*
      -Dhttp.proxyUser=*
      -Dhttp.proxyPassword=*
      -Dhttps.proxyHost=*
      -Dhttps.proxyPort=*
      -Dhttps.proxyUser=*
      -Dhttps.proxyPassword=*
  ```

  without success
- verified the issue in SBT:

  ```
      d:\Users\user1>sbt.bat
      [info] Loading project definition from D:\Users\user1\project
      [info] Updating {file:/D:/Users/user1/project/}user1-build...
      [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(t
      est-jar): typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.l
      og4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.a
      pache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.io.IOE
      xception: Failed to authenticate with proxy (353ms)
      [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(t
      est-jar): sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log
      4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases
      /org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.
      io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy (8ms)
      [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(t
      est-jar): public: unable to get resource for org/apache/logging/log4j#log4j-core
      ;2.8.1: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2
      .8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate wit
      h proxy (8ms)
      [warn]  Detected merged artifact: [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-c
      ore;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar):  (0ms).
      [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
      [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
      [warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logg
      ing.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar
      [warn] ==== local: tried
      [warn]   d:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\
      test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
      [warn] ==== public: tried
      [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.
      1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
      [warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
      [warn]   d:\Users\user1\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8
      .1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
      [warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
      [warn]   file:/d:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-co
      re/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
      [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      [warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
      [warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
      [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      [warn]  :: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
      [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logg
      ing.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve
      (IvyActions.scala:331)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEit
      her$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withMod
      ule$1(Ivy.scala:229)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.
      scala:190)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$libraryman
      agement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:
      77)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withCh
      annelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Lock
      s.scala:99)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scal
      a:60)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
      [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.s
      cala:77)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.s
      cala:228)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyAc
      tions.scala:190)
      [error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyD
      ependencyResolution.scala:20)
      [error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyR
      esolution.scala:56)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.s
      cala:38)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(Libr
      aryManagement.scala:91)
      [error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(Libr
      aryManagement.scala:104)
      [error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)

      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(Libr
      aryManagement.scala:104)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adap
      ted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
      [error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagemen
      t.scala:118)
      [error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
      [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFuncti
      ons.scala:42)
      [error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
      [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
      [error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.sc
      ala:16)
      [error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
      [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
      [error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(Con
      currentRestrictions.scala:167)
      [error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32
      )
      [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors
      .java:511)
      [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolE
      xecutor.java:1149)
      [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPool
      Executor.java:624)
      [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
      Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] (*:update)
       sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logging.log
      4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
  ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, proxy settings (no matter if they were set at Intellij, SBT.conf or environment variables), did not work.

​A couple of considerations that solved this issue (for me at least): 
​

​- if you use SBT 0.13.16 (not newer that that)

​- set Use Auto Import

​
​Then, no "FAILED DOWNLOADS" messages appear.

Answer (score 4):

If you're convinced that this is a proxy issue (and not, say, a temporary network connection problem), then here are your alternatives...

As you mention, you can define a `JVM_OPTS` environment variable specifying *JVM* proxy configuration options. Just to be clear, it's best if this is defined globally (via the *Environment Variables* dialog in the *Windows System* applet, since it looks like you're using *Windows*). If you're not sure how to do this, let me know. **It's important to realize that your existing processes will *not* pick up changes made to global environment variables** - the simplest solution is just to close and restart them.

Another alternative is to put the *JVM* options into a `.jvmopts` file in the root folder of your *SBT* project. (It's a good idea to put project-specific *JVM* options in this file, but not such a good idea to put machine- or site-specific options - such as proxy settings - into such a file. Clearly, if you need login credentials to configure your proxy, don't go this route!) If you pick this option, you need one setting on each line of the file. *SBT* will read any such settings each time it runs.

Either way, it's not clear from your question whether you have specified the *JVM* proxy settings correctly, since `*` is not a valid value for any of them. (If you've just used `*` to replace your actual settings, fair enough.) You'll know best what your proxy settings should be, but - if you have setup system proxy settings for your machine in *Windows* - often the simplest way to configure *Java* applications to use a proxy is to use the following setting:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

or create a `.jvmopts` file with these contents:

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

If you haven't set up system proxy information, you'll need to be more explicit:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxyhost.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxyhost.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=443
```

or, in `.jvmopts`:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxyhost.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=80
-Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxyhost.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=443
```

Note also that if your proxy uses *SOCKS* instead of *HTTP*, then the relevant settings will be:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-DsocksProxyHost=my.proxyhost.com -DsocksProxyPort=8080
```

or, in `.jvmopts`:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=my.proxyhost.com
-DsocksProxyPort=8080
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace these host addresses and port numbers with those for your proxy. (If your domain authenticates you to the proxy server, you shouldn't need to specify username and password settings.)

That should ensure *SBT* works from the command line, and for the occasions that you execute *SBT* tasks from within *IntelliJ* (as a *run configuration*).

However, *IntelliJ* also has it's own proxy settings, which it uses when running *SBT* internally. You'll need to configure this too. You can access the *IntelliJ* proxy settings via the *File/Settings...* menu option, then looking under *Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/HTTP Proxy* (or type 'proxy' into the setting search box):

[image]

Let me know how you get on...