# Exception while building Scala-Maven project on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to build a Scala-Maven project on IntelliJ IDEA. Right after creating the project, it says build successful. This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dbloads.pgms</groupId>
  <artifactId>Arts</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.7.0</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Next I tried to add the compiler options in project like below:
[image]

Once added and when I click the RUN button, I get the below error message:

> [ERROR] Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:jar:3.4.0: Could not transfer artifact net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:pom:3.4.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PITC-Zscaler-EMEA-Amsterdam3PR.proxy.corporate.ge.com: Unknown host PITC-Zscaler-EMEA-Amsterdam3PR.proxy.corporate.ge.com -> [Help 1]

I am using the `jdk version: 1.8.0_172` and I have added the Scala plugin directly from the plugins. Hence it is the latest version of the Scala.
Could anyone let me know how can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to configure *Maven* and *IntelliJ* to use network proxy settings, since it looks like you might be behind a corporate firewall.

Maven has the ability to configure a proxy through its settings (in `~/.m2/settings.xml` on *Unix*-like systems, or `%HOME%\.m2\settings.xml` on *Windows*), as follows:

```xml
<settings ...>
  .
  .
  <proxies>

    <!-- You can have one of these for each possible proxy. -->
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>

      <!-- Pick some ID for your proxy here. -->
      <id>corp-proxy</id>

      <!-- Choose your protocol here. E.g. "http", "socks4" or "socks5" -->
      <protocol>http</protocol>

      <!-- Specify the proxy server name (or IP address) and port of your proxy here. -->
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>

      <!-- Identify any hosts here that you can access directly. It's unlikely that you'll
      need this unless you have a proxy repository (such as Nexus, Artifactory, etc.) on
      your corporate network. -->
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>

      <!-- The following fields are only necessary if required by your proxy. If you need to
      enter your own username and password, make sure you do not add this file to version
      control! -->
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

Meanwhile, *IntelliJ* is configured to use proxies through its settings. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48965290/2593574) for further details. (Note that setting proxy information via the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable will work for running any *Java*/*Scala*/*JVM* application that needs to access the *Internet* via a proxy.)

Alternatively, if your proxy settings are configured correctly or are not required, it might be a temporary network connection issue, so make sure you have an *Internet* connection and try again. (The exception is a failure by *Maven* to download the plugin from the *Maven* central repository.)

BTW, the version of *Scala* you have specified—2.7.0—is *ancient* and almost certainly will not work with *JDK* 8. Either use an older *JDK* or a more recent version of *Scala* (the current release is 2.12.6).

Note that if you need to work with the current version of *Apache Spark*, you must currently use *Scala* 2.11.x - the most recent release being 2.11.12.

**UPDATE**:

From your comments, it seems there is some confusion about the roles played by *Maven*, the *scala-maven-plugin*, *IntelliJ* and the *IntelliJ Scala* plugin, so I'll quickly summarize them here. Please bear with me if I cover topics you're already familiar with...

*Maven* is a system for building and publishing software. (It actually does a lot more than just that, which is why *Maven* describes itself as *project management* software.) It allows developers to specify, in a single place, all of their software's dependencies (third-party libraries used by the software), which *Maven* downloads as required from the [*Central Maven Repository*](http://mvnrepository.com/)—mostly *open-source*—or from other, private repositories, as required. Further settings control how compilers are configured, tests are run, reports generated, etc.

*Maven* was developed primarily for development of *Java*-language projects. The *scala-maven-plugin* provides support for the *Scala* language and compiler within *Maven*. It is this plugin that downloads the version of the *Scala* compiler specified by your project and uses it to compile and build your sources.

If you look at your *Maven* project's `pom.xml` file, you will notice the following lines in the `build` section:

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and again in the `reporting` section:

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

In both cases, there is a line that reads `<scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>`, which tells *Maven* which version of *Scala* you want to use. The plugin then uses this version of the *Scala* compiler, and has *Maven* download it to a cached, local repository on your machine (typically, in `C:\Users\{your account}\.m2` on a *Windows* machine). Note that both *Maven* and the *scala-maven-plugin* will ignore any versions of *Scala* you have installed on your machine.

So which version of *Scala* is the plugin going to download for you? The value `${scala.version}` states that the version number is stored as the value of a property named `scala.version`. Your `pom.xml` file also has lines, near the top, that create this property:

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.7.0</scala.version>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

So, you can see that you will use version 2.7.0 of the *Scala* compiler. If you want to use the latest *Scala* version, you should change this to:

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

OK, so now you will be using the latest version of the *Scala* compiler. Now let's move on to *IntelliJ*...

*IntelliJ IDEA* is an *Integrated Development Environment* (*IDE*), primarily aimed at development with the *Java* language. It provides syntax highlighting, smart code completion, and other features to simplify the process of writing code. In order to provide those features for the *Scala* programming language, you need to install its *Scala* plugin.

You can configure *IntelliJ* to use any version of *Scala* that you have installed on your machine. *IntelliJ* will then know how to compile, build and run your software and can work without using your *Maven project object model* (*POM*) file's build definition.

However, one of the reasons for using *Maven* is to ensure a consistent build environment for developing a project, so that it is not at the whim of whatever each developer may or may not have installed on their machine. For this reason, if a project uses *Maven*, it's a good idea to tell *IntelliJ*. That way, *IntelliJ* can use *Maven*'s `pom.xml` file to specify the version of the compiler, download dependencies, configure the compiler settings, etc.

So, the above information should help you to get up-and-running with your project, working with your corporation's network proxy and using the latest version of *Scala*, using *Maven* and *IntelliJ*.

Comment: But I have added the plugin directly from online. I also tried to get the latest plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala and installed from the disk. But I still get the version as 2.7.0 as you mentions. I have manual proxy set up to bypass any of the company's firewall. Can you tell me what should I do ?

Comment: @Sidhartha I'm not sure what you mean. The fact that you're getting the error means that Maven can't locate the plugin. Where did you put the plugin's files? You have specified the _Scala_ version as 2.7.0 in your `<properties>` section. Why do you need such an old version? Have you tried the proxy settings as I described? (Maven and IntelliJ will not necessarily use your OS's proxy settings.)

Comment: @Sidhartha The plugin you reference in your comment is the _Scala_ language plugin for _IntelliJ_. That provides support for _Scala_ in _IntelliJ_ and has nothing to do with _Maven_. The [`scala-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) provides _Scala_ support within _Maven_, allowing it to compile, test and run your _Scala_ sources. It's this plugin that _Maven_ can't access, in case there's any confusion.

Comment: About your comment on Scala version being 2.7.0, I add the plugin from IntelliJ plugin. I was hoping this would give me the latest version of Scala. I had the proxy setting issue but I added a proxy URL to bypass my organization's firewall. I'll try the scala-maven plugin from your suggestion and put the result here.

Comment: Awesome & perfect answer. Helped a lot and cleared my confusion too.

Comment: @Sidhartha You're welcome! I'm glad I was able to help! Have fun!