# Installing SBT on Win 7 64 bit

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I want to install Apache Spark for testing purpose. For that I found out that Scala and sbt are necessary. I downloaded scala msi and installed it. For installing sbt I tried various methods but am unable to do so. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong. What I did is

1. Install Scala msi
2. Download sbt msi and install it.
3. Set sbt_home and path variable to the location where sbt is extracted.  Then I opened cmd to check my sbt version by using sbt sbt-version I am getting the following error **unresolved dependency:

```
org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found   
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries  (see C:\Users\ashish-b\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)   Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11 **
```

Whats wrong in it?

Comment: Check the log it suggests. Maybe this is an old version of sbt, or the plugin you're trying to invoke depends on a project that no longer exists? This shouldn't really happen, but it sounds like your sbt is working - can you build spark with it? That's your real problem, right?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Please post your answer if you managed to fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue as well when connecting to the internet via a corporate proxy. In this case, sbt couldn't download its dependencies.

We work with a proxy Maven repository for depedencies. [Configure sbt to use a proxy repo](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html).

Our sbt `repositories` file looks like this:

```
[repositories]
    local
    local-maven: file:///C:/data/maven_repo/    
    aaa-ext-ivy-proxy: http://nexus-ext.company.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/ivy-public/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
    aaa-ext-maven-proxy: http://nexus-ext.company.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/
    aaa-int-maven-repo: http://nexus-int.company.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/
```

Or you can also configure the proxy server directly for SBT, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy).

Comment: This must be a long time ago and you might not pick up this comment anymore but I find the same problem and I don't use Proxy