# How to set proxy authentication for using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried to run sbt from terminal by typing sbt. But I am getting a `proxy authentiation failed` error. The error looks like this.

```
                [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.1!compile.jar:  (0ms)
    ==== Maven Central: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compile/0.13.1/compile-0.13.1.jar
    Your proxy requires authentication.
    Your proxy requires authentication.
 ==== Maven Central: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.1/apply-macro-0.13.1.jar
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

            :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: jline#jline;2.11!jline.jar

            :: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.1!incremental-compiler.jar
            :: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.1!compile.jar
g.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.1!persist.jar

            :: org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2!sbinary_2.10.jar

            :: org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.1!classfile.jar
            :: org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.1!cross.jar
            :: org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-rc1!ivy.jar
            :: com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46!jsch.jar



            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I dont know any way how to resolve this.HELP.

Comment: Last lines of error displayed `Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries (see /home/cts357808/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.1`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy