# Install SBT on Linux

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to install SBT for scala developing. I follow the guid in [Installing sbt manually](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html)

The errors show as follows

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7

    ==== local: tried

      /home/nan/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7!sbt.jar:

      /home/nan/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/jars/sbt.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7!sbt.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :::::: ERRORS

    Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.pom

    Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.jar


    :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
    unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found
    Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries (see /home/nan/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
    Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.7
```

The link "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.jar" cannot be accessed even in the browser. Are there any solutions?

Comment: The first link exists: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml . Connection issue?

Comment: I am not sure, but the second link does not exist...

Comment: It can be a proxy problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenter said, it looks like you are just having a network connection problem.

However, if you are not using a package manager, I recommend to use the "sbt-extras" script from [here](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras). I.e.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt \
  > ~/bin/sbt && chmod 0755 ~/bin/sbt
```