# Install SparkR that comes with Spark 1.4

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

The newest version of Spark (1.4) now comes with SparkR. Does anyone know how to go about installing the SparkR implementation on Windows? The sparkR.R script is currently located in C:/spark-1.4.0/R/pkgs/R/

[This](http://sgsong.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/how-to-use-sparkr-within-rstudio.html) appears to be a step in the right direction, but the instructions don't work for Windows as there is no sparkR directory as it relates to.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://sgsong.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/how-to-use-sparkr-within-rstudio.html) maybe

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidArenburg. It seems like it's the right direction, but there is no SparkR directory in the spark-1.4.0 folder so it doesn't exactly provide a solution.

Comment: You can find my solution to a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31252999/3719822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DavidArenburg put me on the right track.

Following the Windows documentation in the C:\spark-1.4.0\R\WINDOWS.md, I installed RTools and added R.exe and RTools to my computers PATH.

Then, I ran install-dev.bat in C:\spark-1.4.0\R This added the lib\SparkR\ installation that I was missing.

Then, from the command prompt, I ran

```
mklink /D "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\library\SparkR" "C:\spark-1.4.0\R\lib\SparkR"
```

This added a link in my R packages directory to the installation in the spark folder.

```
library(SparkR) # this should run now.
```

Answer (score 0):

Frustrated with finding a solution myself, I put together a quick write up [here](http://tbdmark.github.io/InstallSparkR_RStudio.html), which addresses the install on Mac, but it shouldn't be far from implementation in Windows.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @MarkS, That's not too different than [this](http://sgsong.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/how-to-use-sparkr-within-rstudio.html), but certainly still helpful. I've outlined what else is necessary in my answer for Windows.

Comment: Agreed - just wanted to show the end-to-end install as well, since I stumbled upon this thread while searching for an answer for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I could not get it to work with the mklink.

So I very simply copy-pasted the SparkR folder from under my Spark installation (on my computer it's found at: C:\spark\spark\R\lib) to my R library folder (on my computer it's found at: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\library.

And now it's working!