# Error with sparkR installation for R

Tags: r, sparkr

I am trying to install the SparkR Package on my Windows 7 R Studio Version.

So far i get the newest version of R (3.2.0). R Studio (0.98.1103). After that i look at different sources to get an idea about how to install SparkR.

Afterwards i first install "devtools" and Rtools (3.3). But now i dont get any further.

When i try to use one of those

```
install_github("amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg", subdir="pkg")

install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg", subdir="pkg")
```

i get

```
 Downloading github repo amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Timed out
```

I tried to install package manually but that also doesnt work.

Do you have any idea of what do i forget?

Comment: You can find my solution to a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31252999/3719822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution at another ones question that works for me.

[Install SparkR that comes with Spark 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868523/install-sparkr-that-comes-with-spark-1-4)