# sbt 0.13.8 windows 7 unresolved dependencies : org.fusesource.jansi

Tags: scala, proxy, dependencies, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have scala and sbt installed on windows.  I cant use VM box as VT is disabled on the laptop I am using at work.  Using scalac and scala to run a sample program works but I cant get sbt working from commandline.

I have SBT_HOME set to C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\ 
How can I get SBT working?  Any help is appreciated.   The error looks like:

```
 java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar C:\Users\indgorti\.IdeaIC14\system\sbt\sbt-launch.jar 

Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\indgorti\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\indgorti\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: You received "Connection timed out". Check you proxy. Run mentioned addresses from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the proxy for SBT as the same proxy as your local web browser.

Please follow the instructions found at [How to use sbt from behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy#13804254) for setting up the proxy at SBT.