# SBT does not work through a proxy

Tags: scala, proxy, sbt

According to SBT [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup-Notes.html) and SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy) I've tried to make SBT work under proxy. But still get errors

```
[warn] Your proxy requires authentication.
[warn] Your proxy requires authentication.
[warn] Your proxy requires authentication.
[warn]  module not found: com.github.nscala-time#nscala-time_2.11;2.16.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.github.nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/2.16.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/2.16.0/nscala-time_2.11-2.16.0.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/2.16.0/nscala-time_2.11-2.16.0.pom
[warn] ==== scalaz-bintray: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/com/github/nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/2.16.0/nscala-time_2.11-2.16.0.pom
```

I tried:

1. java -Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword settings (both HTTPS)
2. export http(s)_proxy environment variables
3. export JAVA_OPTS
4. export SBT_OPTS
5. update sbtopts file

The ~/.ivy2/cache/ directory contains libraries that sbt cant fetch. My sbt version is 0.13.13. Can anybody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you use proxy for connecting to google.com via curl for example?

Comment: @Mysterion curl works fine. Btw, problem still exists(