# Why is sbt trying to download non-existing dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've downloaded SBT 0.3.15 and I'm trying to run it : for now, I just want to run SBT and get the prompt ; I am not at the stage where I want to build a project yet (even though I expect to be able to do it very soon).

However, I face issues with strange dependencies that SBT tries to download. I initially faced issue with the proxy, but it's better now. The first thing that SBT tries to download is pom.xml for jansi-project 1.11 and it works :

```
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom ...
    Maven Central: downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
        to C:\Users\vfuchs070114\.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml.original.part
sha1 file found for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom: checking...
    Maven Central: downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom.sha1
    to C:\Users\VFUCHS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ivytmp1821470066062959950sha1
sha1 OK for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
[SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.pom(pom.original) (1085ms)
```

The next file it tries to download is fusesource-pom-1.8.jar from Maven central repo :

```
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/fusesource-pom-1.8.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/fusesource-pom-1.8.jar
```

And here are a couple more :

- https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/jars/fusesource-pom.jar
- https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/ivys/ivy.xml
- https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/ivys/ivy.xml
- https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi-project/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
- https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi-project/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
- https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
- https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

Then it fails... Since even through my browser I don't see anything available on these URLs, I'm ruling out a proxy config issue.

how am I supposed to get these dependencies, and from where ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your `build.sbt`? And contents of your `project/` directory.

Comment: Looking at the first URL, I found `fusesource-pom.jar` in maven repo here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8 

So you probably need to add maven repository to your list of resolvers.

Like @Reactormonk said, post your build.sbt.

Comment: actually, I'm not trying to build a project yet - I've just downloaded SBT (the zip version), and trying to run it. I understand I should at least have a prompt, but I don't. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @RobertUdah, unless I'm missing something obvious with regards to the jar , the link you provided clearly says that "This is a shared POM parent for FuseSource Maven projects". We see here that only a pom is available, not the jar : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of struggle, I don't have the exact answer to my question, but I've been able to find a workaround.

1. downloading dependencies through the corporate proxy just doesn't work and I don't know why. I configure SBT with same properties that I configure git : I'm able to clone GitHub projects, but SBT isn't able to get the dependencies. There's not enough specific infos in SBT logs to investigate anything, so I gave up this option.
2. we have Nexus as internal artifactory and proxy for external repositories. I asked the team in charge of it to create a new repository on our Nexus, mirroring https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ , and then added the internal repositories URL in my config, as suggested here : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

   ```
   maven-internal-thirdparty-proxy: internal_proxy_url, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly

   ivy-internal-typesafe-proxy: internal_proxy_url, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
   ```
3. I had to remove the internet proxy config I had put initially, to make sure SBT doesn't try to go through internet proxy to reach the internal proxy repos.