# IntelliJ cannot resolve jsDependency when connected to corporate VPN

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, webjars

When I'm connected to my company's VPN, IntelliJ is unable to resolve certain jsDependencies.

I have set proxy settings in IntelliJ to point to my corporate proxy server, but this seems to make no difference.

If I disconnect from the VPN, then everything builds fine...

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] 
Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-server;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-continuation;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.webjars#jquery;2.1.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3 ((org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal) ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala#L996)
[warn]        +- weatherreportui5:weatherreportui5_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.webjars#jquery;2.1.3: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.webjars#jquery;2.1.3: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 04-Sep-2017 17:31:13</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.2/sbt.last.log">file:/Users/i003638/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.2/sbt.last.log</a>
```

The sbt.last.log file complains:

```
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.webjars#jquery;2.1.3
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/xxxxxx/.ivy2/local/org.webjars/jquery/2.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/xxxxxx/.sbt/preloaded/org.webjars/jquery/2.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/xxxxxx/.sbt/preloaded/org/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.pom
```

If this is a problem with my company's proxy server, then I'm not sure why putting the Maven URL into my browser (when connected to the VPN) displays the POM file without any problems.

Also, the path name to the Ivy2 cache shown in sbt.last.log does not match the actual path to the cache on disk.  It should be ~/.ivy2/cache.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The dependency resolution is run by `sbt` (by delegating to Apache Ivy). I doubt the problem is in intellij. Check [how to use sbt from behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy) and then post here if it works

Comment: Ah, it appears that SBT has its own proxy settings independent from IntelliJ. 
 I think it was the VM parameter settings in Preferences -> Build, Execution and Deployment -> SBT.

Comment: Is it fixed? Should this be close?

Comment: Yes, working now.  Thanks

Comment: Delete the question or answer it yourself :) unanswered questions make my ocd itch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the VM parameter settings in IntelliJ.

Preferences -> Build, Execution and Deployment -> SBT.

Needed to add:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=hostname
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=hostname
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```