# IntelliJ not connecting to internet when my organization vpn is connected?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I tried to make gradle build, but intellij not downloading my dependency.
I am connected to my organization VPN, also tried automatic HTTP proxy
and custom vm argument no luck. I tried test connection in proxy settings it failing with VPN.
But without VPN  test connection  is success. Week before both ways its working. Can't understood sudden problem. Any solutions
Intellij Version 2019.1.2

Comment: Try to contact your network administrators. Sounds like the VPN itself blocks those connections.

Comment: for other team mates its working

Comment: What @Maksym Rudenko shared looks reasonable :)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't encounter this problem myself, but from what I see in the internet, this is most likely not an IDEA problem, but a "Grandle through VPN" problem.

Some googling shows up next:

[How to configure Grandle with VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)

[Example of fixing SBT proxy in IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041732/intellij-cannot-resolve-jsdependency-when-connected-to-corporate-vpn)