# Intellij not able to import SBT dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have following in my SBT dependencies but IntelliJ keeps giving error unresolved artifacts. Not sure how to fix this.

```
libraryDependencies += "io.opentracing" %  "opentracing-api" % "0.30.0"
libraryDependencies += "io.opentracing" %  "opentracing-util" % "0.30.0"
```

Comment: Have you [imported](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt.html#import_sbt) the project as SBT project? Have you refreshed the project in SBT tool window after adding dependencies? Do other dependencies appear if you add them?
  Check also that you can build it from command line.

Comment: Yes its imported as SBT project and I did the refresh. But its still unresolved. Command line also fails. Not sure why SBT cannot access the lib

Comment: Check that you have the remote repository, where this library is located, added in build.sbt file. If you have proxies in network, check the https://stackoverflow.com/a/13804254/2000323